# Can't see properties error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Have an error message on some properties. The error messages are commented out in the following code. Don't understand why I get this error message even though the properties are declared and synthesized in other files?

PlayersViewController.m

```
#import "PlayersViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayerCell.h"


@implementation PlayersViewController

@synthesize players;


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.players count];
}

- (UIImage *)imageForRating:(int)rating
{
    switch (rating) {
        case 1:return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1StarSmall.png"];
        case 2:return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2StarsSmall.png"];
        case 3:return [UIImage imageNamed:@"3StarsSmall.png"];
        case 4:return [UIImage imageNamed:@"4StarsSmall.png"];
        case 5:return [UIImage imageNamed:@"5StarsSmall.png"];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name; /*property 'nameLabel' not found on object of tupe "UITableViewCell" */
    cell.gameLabel.text = player.game; /*property 'gameLabel' not found on object of tupe "UITableViewCell" */
    cell.ratingImageView.image = [self imageForRating:player.rating]; /*property 'ratingImageView' not found on object of tupe "UITableViewCell" */
    return cell;
}
```

The properties are declared and implemented in the following two files:

PlayerCell.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *game;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int rating; 

@end
```

PlayerCell.m

```
#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize name;
@synthesize game;
@synthesize rating;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewCell does not have a property called nameLabel, gameLabel or ratingImageView. If you are using your own custom UITableViewCell subclass then you need to tell the compiler that you're sending messages to an instance of a `PlayerCell` and not UITableViewCell.

do it like this

`PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];`

Alternatively, you can use `id` and the compiler won't have a problem if you don't use dot notation but I'd use the explicit class version for clarity.

```
id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
[cell nameLabel].text = @""; //etc
```

**As an aside** - if that's your actual code then you're not instantiating your UITableViewCells which could also prove problematic.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
if (nil == cell){
  cel = [[[PlayerCell alloc] yourInitMethodWithCellIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
cell.gameLabel.text = player.game;
cell.ratingImageView.image = [self imageForRating:player.rating];
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a file called "PlayerCell.m" that creates instances of "Player" which is an `NSObject`. Instead, you should have "PlayerCell.m" create instances of "PlayerCell" which should be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

From there, `PlayerCell` should have properties `UILabel *nameLabel` and `UILabel *gameLabel`, etc.

The snippets you gave that you called "PlayerCell.h" and "PlayerCell.m" look fine if they are actually "Player.h" and "Player.m" instead.